# Error in scheduled transformation Pentaho

Tags: database, pentaho

I tried running the transformation on Pentaho and there was no error but once I run the transformation in the scheduler of Pentaho it always report this error:

```
2014/05/27 12:52:03 - biotime - Dispatching started for transformation [biotime]
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.6, build 1 from 2014-04-26_17-32-54 by buildguy) : An error occurred, processing will be stopped: 
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - Error occured while trying to connect to the database
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - 
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - Error connecting to database: (using class sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver)
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.6, build 1 from 2014-04-26_17-32-54 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [department_bio]
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - biotime - ERROR (version 5.0.6, build 1 from 2014-04-26_17-32-54 by buildguy) : Step [department_bio.0] failed to initialize!
2014/05/27 12:52:04 - department_bio.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
```

Can someone explain this error? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: which PDI version you are using and how you are scheduling the transformation? i mean the steps of scheduler..

Just refer this link and match you are doing in the same way..
http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Ftask_pdi_usr_scheduling_trans_jobs.html

Comment: I'm using version 5.0 and I have done the same step as with the link you gave me.

Comment: i never worked with 5.0.. wait for someone Else's reply.

Answer (score 1):

I guess with the scheduler the transformation runs inside the DI-Server.

Therefore copy your driver to
/pentaho/server/data-integration-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho-di/WEB-INF/lib/

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help48/index.jsp?topic=%2Fadmin_guide%2Fconcept_adding_a_jdbc_driver.html

Comment: Adding to your explanation, I suggest not using ODBC but JDBC only. ODBC is windows only, somewhat buggy and slower than JDBC.